# linear independence and span proof problem

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, linear-independence

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and that $X\subset V$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$. If $S(X)$ is a proper subset of $V$, then there exists a set $X’\subset V$ such that $X$ is a proper subset of $X′$, and $X′$ is a linearly independent set.

How do I prove this claim?

Comment: What is the purpose of $S(X)$ ? It it used nowhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $S(X)$ refers to the span of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $S(X)$ refers to $\operatorname{span}(X)$, and I will refer to the field we are working over as $F$.

Since $\operatorname{span}(X)\ne V$, there exists a vector $a\in V\setminus \operatorname{span}(X)$. I claim that $X’ = X\cup\{a\}$ is linearly independent. Because $X$ is already linearly independent, it suffices to just check linear combinations containing the newly added element $a$.

Suppose $c_1x_1 + \ldots + c_nx_n + c_{n+1}a = 0$, where each $c_i\in F$ and $x_i\in X$. Because $F$ is a field, each $c_i\ne 0$ has a multiplicative inverse $c_i^{-1}$, whence

$$c_{n+1}a = -(c_1x_1+\ldots + c_nx_n)$$

and thus, if $c_{n+1}\ne 0$,

$$a = -c_{n+1}^{-1}(c_1x_1+\ldots + c_nx_n)\in\operatorname{span}(X).$$

So, if $c_{n+1}\ne 0$, $a\in\operatorname{span}(X)$, which is a contradiction. As such, $c_{n+1}=0$. But then we have

$$c_1x_1 + \ldots + c_nx_n=0,$$

which means each $c_i=0$ due to the linear independence of $X$. Therefore, $X’$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE! Since you are new, you may not know that per a [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), users are not supposed to answer questions that do not show any effort or context from the asker. Your answers are pretty high quality though :)! Good luck!

Comment: @bobeyt6 sorry about that; I wasn’t aware of this. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No. The site's goal is to be a useful repository of answers and questions, and since your answer is high quality, I think it should be fine to leave it here. Just keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @bobeyt6 Sounds good. I will keep it in mind, and thank you for making me aware of this.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't add a context. @PhilipSpeegle I'm grateful for the solution